# Is there an offset or an error on the altitude returned in shape from Here Routing API?

Tags: routes, here-api

I am trying to get the elevation of a route using the routing API from HERE.
There is a property that can be used on the Routing API, `returnElevation` ([API Documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html)), which adds elevation to any route shape returned from the API.
The property works as intended, and any shape returned from the API does go from 2 values to 3 values. However, the 3rd value returned in any shape seems to be offset by a value that I cannot figure out, and am unable to find any information about.

I have made the following request;

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&routeAttributes=all&departure=now&app_id=&app_code=&waypoint0=57.6861585,11.894235&waypoint1=57.6860409,11.893575&returnElevation=true
```

And get a result which contains the following shape;

```
"shape": [
   "57.6861727,11.8941915,38.0",
   "57.6860616,11.8935622,38.0"
 ]
```

This I would interpret as if the altitude at this point is 38m above sea level. The problem is that I took a known location in my own city, which I know is right next to the sea. (Looking up this location via other sources I get it is roughly 3m above sea level).

It does not seem to be that it is an offset of 35 either, because if I take another position that I know the altitude of, it can differ by another value.

Is there a known issue with the altitude values in the routing API?

Comment: Thank you for reporting this observation. We are looking into it internally and will get back to you soon.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Great! Can you verify that this is an issue or am I not using the API correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct of getting elevation by setting **returnelevation** field to true. Also does it returning incorrect response for other close by areas or is it just your place.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html

however if there is incorrect data which is coming in response, then you can report it via:

1. Map creator (locate the poi and make the change, Here team will review and approve it)
2. Use Map Feedback API: https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/key-concepts-submit-feedback.html

Comment: I have tested two different locations that I know are very close to sea level. Both return values of around 38-39 (location1: 57.669991,11.850067 location2: 55.675718,12.576160). It seems like it is not just one instance of data which is incorrect, but rather an underlying offset of some sort that causes issues.
The problem seems to exist on a number of different locations, therefore I cannot report all of them (as it seems to be global).